# How to change property in a cloned object, and all properties in the original object not changed

Tags: typescript, object, deep-copy

I have a problem about changing property in a cloned object.

the origial object looks like this:

```
originObject = {a: otherObject1, b: otherObject2}

and in OtherObject1 = {p1: number, p2: boolean}
and in OtherObject2= {p3: boolean, p4: string}
```

in this origin object the property a and b are also object.

now I want to clone this originObject to

```
clonedObject = {a: otherObject1, b: otherObject2}
```

I have tried to use Spread {...originalObject} to clone originalObject to change value p1 in clone object, but the p1 in originalObject was also changed.

I have tried to use Deep copy

```
const clonedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
clonedObject.a.p1 = 3;
```

there is also a problem in browser bebug: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

any solutions?

Comment: Adding some code with expected inputs and outputs would be very helpful. It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Can you please define "not working". The only thing you don't get with the JSON approach is methods coming across. Should work in all other circumstances.